# How to sandbox java using Graalvm

Tags: graalvm

graal can sandbox js, ruby and other languages when create context, but how to sandbox a dynamic loaded jar? For example, how to sandbox a custom uploaded jar when used in flink as udf.

Answer (score 1):

Java bytecodes can currently not be sandboxed using the polygot API [1]. Like with any other JDK you can sandbox a jar by creating a new classloader [2].

```
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(myJar.toURL(), 
this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class classToLoad = Class.forName("com.MyClass", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod");
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
Object result = method.invoke(instance);
```

[1] http://www.graalvm.org/docs/graalvm-as-a-platform/embed/

[2] [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Comment: Is it possible that implement a guest language jvm bytecode interpreter to support sandbox using the polyglot API?

Comment: Yes. That is a possibility. And we are working on such an interpreter atm.